# In Beauty and the Beast, what if the Prince showed kindness to the Enchantress?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast

In the prologue of both Disney Beauty and the Beast adaptations, the Prince turned down the old woman simply because of her appearance, so she turned into the Enchantress and cursed the castle.

**Is there any indication of how (or if) the Enchantress would have rewarded him if he'd shown her kindness?**

Comment: My impression was that she'd already heard that he was a git and just wanted proof before she cursed him. If he'd shown her kindness, she probably would have just thanked him and left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Beast considers this possibility in the comic serial *Disney's Beauty and the Beast* (#13).

In short, No mention is made of a reward, but he thinks it likely that ***if he had shown her kindness, she wouldn't have cursed him***.

[image]

Comment: Seems more like speculation on his part than anything certain, but it's a good find regardless.